# Onde estou errando? Um código que tenta recuperar dados de um banco de dados do Access com VB.NET

Tags: sql, visual-studio, vb.net, microsoft-access

Eu tenho um Windows `Form` no Visual Studio Code onde tenho um botão que executa o código abaixo.
Ele lê um valor `X` na `textbox1` e deveria retornar um valor `Y` que está no banco de dados.

Se ao digitar 100 na `texbox1` e executar o código ele me traz o valor 100-190421 na `textbox2`, mas se eu pesquisa 100-190421 na `textbox1` eu não consigo trazer nem o valor da coluna `COD` nem o valor da coluna `MYNAME`. **(esse é meu problema).**Embora os dados existam no banco de dados ele retorna o erro **Nã há linha na posição 0**, o que está me dando muita dor de cabeça, tenho pesquisado muito mas não encontrei ainda uma resposta.

'''

```
    Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\bd.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=Strawberry21;")
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select * from Table1 where REG=" & TextBox1.Text, conn)
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim publictable As New DataTable

    conn.Open()

    Try

        da.Fill(publictable)
        TextBox2.Text = publictable.Rows(0).Item(2).ToString

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    Finally

        conn.Close()

    End Try
```

'''

Segue uma imagem do BD.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o campo reg é texto certo? use aspas simples na query: `"Select * from Table1 where REG='" & TextBox1.Text &"'"`

Comment: Oi Ricardo, o campo REG é texto sim, eu tentei mas também não funcionou, retornou o mesmo erro :(, mas vlw :D

Comment: tentou executar a query no banco direto? verifique se tem espaços, mas um campo texto deve ter aspas simples sempre

Comment: Consegui Ricardo, sua correção estava certa, eu refiz a consulta e deu super certo, muitíssimo grato!! Na primeira vez que fui consultar errei um dígito no valor da pesquisa.

Answer (score -1):

Falta finalizar seu código, o atual não está fechado.

```
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select * from Table1 where REG=" & TextBox1.Text, conn)
```

Altere para esta forma, adicionando ao final o item: **& "')"**

```
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select * from Table1 where REG=('" & TextBox1.Text & "')", conn)
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).